# Что более востребовано во фрилансе?

Tags: работа

Администрирую сервера, путь к успеху вижу: потихоньку изучаю все технологии, прохожу сертификации, получаю опыт. Но что-то захотелось мне махнуть на пол года в Тайланд, и нужна удаленная работа. Что бы начать копать в свободное время?

Comment: какой же спорный вопрос...Erlang

Comment: > прохожу сертификации

А что за сертификации? Где проходить? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, наиболее востребован веб дизайн и верстка, но что-то мне подсказывает, что не выживете вы на этом находясь полгода в Тайланде. Ну на тарелку риса, конечно, хватит, но на иные радости, включая прекрасных туземок, вряд ли.

Поищите какой-нибудь стартап, благо их теперь развелось как собак нерезаных. Стартап хорош тем, что это более-менее стабильный источник существования (ну пока стартап не накроется медным тазом), во вторых нет жесткой привязки к рабочему месту. В общем это нечто среднее между фрилансом и постоянкой.

**Update**

Собственно о технологии для изучения: посмотрите в сторону мобильных технологий. Острие прогресса (соответственно и стартапы) сейчас находятся там.

Comment: да ладно, какой рис?)
или вы считаете что я прям сейчас, с пустой головой пакую чемоданы?
неужели нельзя через пол год-два иметь удаленную работу в те же 40-50к?

Comment: 40-50k это как раз и есть рис - ну с мясом правда :)

Comment: 40-50к это вполне ок. Дом c wifi у бассейна 19 + мопед 2. Остальное на еду, кайфы, обратную дорогу и хомячковое накопительство.

Answer (score 2):

Я уже больше года в Тае. Видел и стартаперов с тонущего стартапа, и покерщиков, и SMM спецов и прогеров сильных, и каких-то биржевых монстров с ботами.

Тут минус в жаре и влажности: попробуй поработать в натопленной бане. Во всяком случае, на нашем "райском" острове Самуи так. На два месяца мы уезжали в Куала Лумпур (Малайзия) - там раза в два лучше работалось: город, и хорошие апартаменты. Воздух другой. Тоже жара, но сухая, что ли. Если бы не сложности с визой, выбрал бы К-Л для длительной остановки. Ну или Сингапур! Дорогой, но там и айти-работ полно. В т.ч. админских.

По клиентам — у меня были два стартапа, свои проекты, по мелочи клиенты и всякие англоязычные *-лансы. Веб разработка, стриминг, облака.

Answer (score 0):

Веб-дизайн, верстка и веб-программирование. Особенно верстка и работать я советую только на  [censored!]

Comment: @took, какой у Вас опыт работы (сколько лет) ?

Comment: @avp если вам это реально интересно, то посмотрите вопросы, которые задавал пользователь.